# What's the mass of a neutron star under the given circumstances? (simple physics NOT ASTRONOMY)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

Suppose a neutron star has 1 rev/s along it's axis. It's radius is 20 km. Now for how much mass ,an object will have no acceleration. I tried g=w^2 *r and from there I get M=1.198*10^23 but my book says it's 2.37*10^20.

Comment: The surface gravity of a neutron star is not given by a Newtonian formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effective acceleration due to gravity due to rotation is g' = g - ω² R cos²φ. Here, φ = latitude and g = GM/R².

Use this approach and find the desired result by putting all the values, correctly.